# Is it possible to rename "_id" to something else while aggregating in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following query

```py
collection.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"timestamp": {"$gte": lastDateInUnix}} },
        {   "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%d-%m-%Y",
                        "date": {
                            "$toDate": {
                                "$multiply": [1000, "$timestamp"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "totalMessages": {"$sum": 1 }
            }
        }
    ])
```

This returns something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "05-01-2020",
        "totalMessages": 4
    }
]
```

As "_id" is a required field, is it possible to rename "_id" to say "dateOccurred"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `$project` to do that, `_id` is a required field for documents existing in DB, but you transform the document or result the way you like using `.aggregate()` or `.find()` which are two ways you retrieve data from DB :

```
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "timestamp": { "$gte": lastDateInUnix } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%d-%m-%Y",
                    "date": {
                        "$toDate": {
                            "$multiply": [1000, "$timestamp"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "totalMessages": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { $project: { dateOccurred: '$_id', totalMessages: 1, _id: 0 } }
])
```